# Javascript ES6 constants in class property undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm making automated e2e tests in Protractor with Selenium.
I have a class in which I want to store a property to maintain my tests better.

Here's the class in question :

```
export class Tab {
    constructor(job) {
      this._criterionList = [];
      this._job = job;
      this._JOBBASEPATH = element(by.css_sr('iris-app::sr #jobs'))
        .all(by.css_sr('::sr iris-job')).get(this.getIndex());

      this._ACTIONMENUBASEPATH = this._JOBBASEPATH
        .element(by.css_sr('::sr #header'))
        .element(by.css_sr('::sr iris-floating-menu'));

      this._JOBFOOTERBASEPATH = this._JOBBASEPATH
        .element(by.css_sr('::sr job-footer'));

      this._RESULTBASEPATH = this._JOBBASEPATH
      .element(by.css_sr('::sr #result'));
    }
}
```

However, when calling one of my methods inside this same class :

```
//Method in Tab class, this._JOBBASEPATH is undefined
getQueryConditionButton(){
  return this._JOBBASEPATH
    .element(by.css_sr('::sr #header'))
    .element(by.css_sr('::sr #condition'));
}
// _JOBBASEPATH is undefined
tab.getQueryConditionButton().click();
```

Debug tells me "No element found using locator: by.css_sr("::sr #header")",
I tried calling this._JOBBASEPATH.click() and _JOBBASEPATH is undefined.

I found workarounds like creating getters/setters or methods doing the exact same thing but I want to understand
why this doesn't work, especially when I successfully implemented it in other classes like this one :

```
export class DetailField {
    constructor(tab) {
        this._tab = tab;
        this._displayFieldList = [];
        this._basePath = element(by.css_sr('iris-app::sr #jobs'))
         .all(by.css_sr('::sr iris-job')).get(this._tab.getIndex())
         .element(by.css_sr('::sr #customizer'))
         .element(by.css_sr('::sr #detailField'));
    }
}

//Method in DetailField class working perfectly
getLoadButton(){
    return this._basePath
     .element(by.css_sr('::sr #loadButton'));
}
//works
getLoadButton().click();
```

Note : the getIndex() call returns the same value for both classes : 0
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provider a JSFiddle? Then it is much easier to help you and try to understand what you want to do :)

Comment: @lightstalker89 As I use protractor API, it isn't possible to have a complete replica. I'll try tho

Comment: Alright. Just try it, and if it does not work, well try to get it working in any other way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `this.getIndex()` to `0`:

```
this._JOBBASEPATH = element(by.css_sr('iris-app::sr #jobs'))
       .all(by.css_sr('::sr iris-job'))
       .get(0);
```

if above code work, the issue comes from `this.getIndex()`.

if not work, the issue comes from `element(...).all(...)`, it not find any elements, so `get(0)` return undefined.

Check the locator manually to see it can find element?  If yes, add some sleep to wait page loading.

Comment: Well for now I made this method which does the exact same thing as above and it works like a charm, I tried setTimeout to wait a bit but it doesn't change anything.

    `getJobBasePath(){
        return  element(by.css_sr('iris-app::sr #jobs'))
          .all(by.css_sr('::sr iris-job')).get(this._job.getTabIndex(this));
      }`

Comment: Can you print out the value of  `this._job.getTabIndex(this)` by  `console.log(this._job.getTabIndex(this))`,   Is it return a promise?

Comment: please show the function code `getTabIndex()` of _job

Comment: from console.log after using the command `let tab = job.addTab()` addTab() returns the created tab:
 `tab.getIndex() :  0
tab._job.getTabIndex(tab) :  0`

Comment: I think I got it, I was adding the tab in the job._tabList[] after creating the tab object, this means that calling this.getTabIndex() was returning null. I can't have it as a property as the index of the tab can change. This also means I have to stop using properties as basePath in my other classes.